Topologies on the space of smooth functions
Let $M$ be a compact manifold. Consider $C^{\infty}(M, \mathbb{R})$, the space of smooth, real-valued functions on $M$. I've read about two topologies on $C^{\infty}(M, \mathbb{R})$. One is the [Whitney $C^{\infty}$-topology]
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_topologies), which is completely metrizable since $M$ is compact. The other is the Fréchet topology, which also admits a complete metric $d_{C^{\infty}}$ described as follows. Let $g$ be an auxiliary Riemannian metric on $M$. For $f \in C^{\infty}(M, \mathbb{R})$, let $\| f \|_{C^k} = \sum_{j=0}^{k} \sup |\nabla^j f|_g$, where $\nabla^j f$ is the $j$-th covariant derivative and $| \cdot |_g$ is the Riemannian norm. Then
\begin{equation*}
d_{C^{\infty}}(f, h) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{\| f - h \|_{C^k}}{1 + \| f - h \|_{C^k}}
\end{equation*}
It is easy to see that $d(f_n, f) \to 0$ if and only if $\| f_n - f \|_{C^k} \to 0$ for all $k$.
Do the two topologies coincide? My intuition says yes, but the definition of the Whitney $C^{\infty}$-topology is a bit long and I'm not sure how to work with it. I appreciate any insight and pointers to references.

Would the open mapping theorem prove that the obvious map is a TVS isomorphism? I would have to study the Whitney topology to see that it gives a Frechet space, etc... (I did take the liberty of adding the functional analysis tag ... )
